# What does apt-daily.service do?

Tags: apt, startup

I searched the internet, and could not find any significant information about it.

Making a wild guess, it performs a daily check for available updates.
Is it so?

But then, it significantly slows my startup!

Also, I have disabled automatic updates, and have a habit of checking for, and installing, updates every time I start my computer.

So..... Isn't it wise to stop this service?

**Edit: Response of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`**

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @30.394s
└─gdm.service @29.795s +598ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @26.524s +361ms
    └─network.target @26.521s
      └─networking.service @20.093s +6.427s
        └─apparmor.service @15.701s +3.970s
          └─local-fs.target @15.699s
            └─boot-efi.mount @15.389s +310ms
              └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1860\x2d9879.service @14.786s +574ms
                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1860\x2d9879.device @14.785s
```

Any guidance is really appreciated.

Regards,
Abbas.

Comment: Since you believe that apt-daily service is slowing your startup, please edit your question to include the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Although apt-daily.service is not present in this list, it is clearly visible through 'systemd-analyze plot' and 'systemd-analyze blame' puts it on the top of the list!

Comment: Plot and blame are indeed useful for many purposes, but may mislead since systemd runs many operations in parallel. In this case, critical-chain shows that apt-daily.service, while slow, is not among the services that systemd is waiting upon: Boot is waiting for your disk to mount (takes 15 seconds due to fsck), and networking to come up (6 seconds). You CAN stop apt-daily...but it is unlikely to speed your boot.

Comment: @user535733. Thanks for the details. But I still don't know what this service actually does!

Comment: You were correct - it performs a daily check for updates, and triggers Unattended-Upgrades (if enabled). It rarely does the check at startup time. It's usually set to a random time each day by a systemd timer (see https://askubuntu.com/a/934863/19626 for some details)/